# 〜がほしがっています vs 〜をほしがっています

Tags: particle-が, particle-を

I was wondering if the following two sentences have the same meaning. I'm seeing both `をほしい` and `がほしい` on my `Anki deck` and I was just wondering if they were interchangeable or if I just made a mistake when I was adding them in.

> トムさんはともだち**を**ほしがっています。
>
> トムさんはともだち**が**ほしがっています。

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

欲しい is an adjective, "を + adjective" is not common, "が + adjective" is common, so が欲しい is common.

欲しがる is a verb and mainly used as a transitive verb, so を is usually placed before 欲しがる.

Answer (score 4):

Grammaticaly speaking, を is the right choice here because of がる being attached to ほしい. If ほしい is alone, then が is the right choice. But you may find both, still, がほしい is way more common than をほしい and をほしがっている is more frequent that がほしがっている.

Comment: So it's like this 〜がほしい and 〜をほしがる?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Answer (score 2):

## Case 1:

When the speaker itself is the subject:

- （私は、）新しい車がほしい。I want a new car.
- （私は、）あなたに一万円を（私に）貸してほしい。I want you to lend ten thousands yen (to me).

## Case 2:

When the speaker wants to say that someone (third person) wants something or wants to do something:

- 彼は新しい車をほしがっている。He wants a new car.
- 彼はあなたに一万円を（彼に）貸してほしがっている。He wants you to lend ten thousands yen (to him).

## Case 3:

When the speaker wants to ask someone (second person):

- 新しい車がほしいですか。 Do you want a new car?
- 一万円を貸してほしいですか。Do you want me to lend ten thousands yen?

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that  `ほしがる` is always paired with `を`?

Comment: And `objectがほしい` is always with `が` and `を〜て form+ほしい` is always with `を`.